# Avoid Ajax loaded content for search engine bots

Tags: seo, ajax

A website I run has a lot of content that is being loaded using Ajax. The reason for using Ajax is that the content generation takes some time (a few seconds), because it loads data from other websites using their respective APIs.

My concern is, that search engine bots will not see any useful content. The solution I've been thinking about would be to serve search engine bots differently, so that the content will be displayed directly for them. Technically, this would not be a big problem.

My question is: Will search engines (read: Google) consider this behaviour as website cloaking? Are there other concerns I might not have considered?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution for this is to generate a static version of the content using a headless browser of some kind. Full details can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started